# AWS Go sdk load unmarshal AttributeValue from JSON

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sdk, amazon-dynamodb

I have exported a DynamoDB table to S3 using Dynamo JSON.
Then I want to read this JSON from a Go program and using `aws-sdk-go-v2` read the string from file and remove the Dynamo types.

For example, the export file looks like:
`{"Item":{"userId":{"S":"XXX"},"userEmail":{"S":"YYY"}}}` and ideally I want to convert it to `{"userId": "XXX" ,"userEmail":"YYY"}`

The source structure can be more complex containing Maps so I would like to avoid manual parsing.

I am trying with `attributevalue.(Un)Marshal` but with no luck so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried and is failing. What do you mean with `attributevalue.(Un)Marshal`? Since you want to (un)marshal JSON, you should be using `json.(Un)Marshal`